# How to Select JObject in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, csv, json.net

I Have Json Like this

```
{
    "operation": {
        "result": {
            "message": "Request Details fetched successfully",
            "status": "Success"
        },
        "Details": [
            {
                "Name" : "Ezio",
                "NOTIFICATION STATUS": "OKOC",

            },
            {
                "Name" : "Altair",
                "NOTIFICATION STATUS": "OKOC",

            },
}
```

and at first i want to convert this json into csv file but it says json cant start from Object and need to be array, as can you see i need to get rid of operation so i will get Details Only.

```
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
  JObject Line2 = JObject.Parse(responseString);
            JArray array = (JArray)Line2["Details"];
```

so i tried with that code above but it shows error message `Object reference not set to  an of an Object "array was null"` so its look like i didnt get anything from array because its null? anyone can help me here thanks

Comment: Is this JSON correct?

Comment: Details are inside "operation" object, not directly inside root.

Comment: `(JArray)Line2["operation"]["Details"];` may be this.

Comment: yeah you right it inside operaton , ok i will try @ruhul solution

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ruhul mentioned in his comment I was able to retrive `Details` using following code:

```
JArray array = (JArray)line2["operation"]["Details"];
```

With the following JSON:

```
{
  "operation": {
    "result": {
      "message": "Request Details fetched successfully",
      "status": "Success"
    },
    "Details": [
      {
        "Name": "Ezio",
        "NOTIFICATION STATUS": "OKOC"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Altair",
        "NOTIFICATION STATUS": "OKOC"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]